# Drawing rectangle does not work in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

The program should draw a rectangle on click. But it does not. Maybe some problem with my understanding of delegates. What's the catch?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace forms1
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            //this.Paint+= new PaintEventHandler(MujPaintHandler);

            this.Click += new EventHandler(MujClickHandler);

        }

        public void MujPaintHandler(object sender,PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics gfx=e.Graphics;
            gfx.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.DarkViolet),100,100,200,200);
        }

        public void MujClickHandler(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text="aaaaa";
            this.Paint+= new PaintEventHandler(MujPaintHandler);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me... are you seeing the text changing, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try forcing a redraw after assigning the event handler:

```
    public void MujClickHandler(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text="aaaaa";
        this.Paint+= new PaintEventHandler(MujPaintHandler);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
```

Also, if you click twice, the event handler gets assigned twice, which is not something you want.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've written works for me, but your form's window has to be big enough to show the rectangle.

Diagnostically, the first thing I'd check is whether the title of the form changes to "aaaaa". If it does, then you know the click handler is being called - but maybe you've got a problem with the paint handler. If it doesn't, then for some reason your click handler isn't being called.

Note that this isn't the normal way you'd draw a rectangle on a click in Windows Forms, but I'm assuming this is just a learning exercise.

Comment: Okay, so how would you write that program? What is wrong about this approach?

Comment: @Dunemaster: Assuming that normally you'd want potentially many rectangles, I'd override OnPaint and keep a variable with a list of rectangles to draw within OnPaint. The click handler would add to that list and then invalidate the form to force a repaint.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to force a redraw. Does the rect appear if you move the window? Just call the PaintHandler after click.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are only attaching the Paint event handler. You are not invoking the Paint event.

Try this

```
public void MujClickHandler(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
this.Text="aaaaa";
this.Paint+= new PaintEventHandler(MujPaintHandler);
this.Invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will only draw the rectangle if it happens to be inside the area that is invalidated to update the text that you change.

When you change the text, it creates a message that the text has to be redrawn, which will call the `Paint` event to do the drawing. The event will have a `Graphics` object that is clipped to the rectangle that needs to be redrawn to update the text, so only the part of the rectangle that intersects with the text will be drawn.

You have to cause a redraw that covers the entire rectangle, so the easiest is to cause the whole window to be redrawn:

```
this.Invalidate();
```

Note that you should not hook up the `Paint` event from the `Click` event handler. That means that the event will be hooked up one more time each click, so after five clicks the `Paint` event handler will be called five times every time something needs to be redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I understand that you are trying to add an eventhandler for paint event on Click... You would also need to invoke the paint event..  Here is a sample code where I am assigning the Paint EventHandler on a button click and raising the paint event on the click as you are doing

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Click += new EventHandler(MujClickHandler);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(MujPaintHandler);
    }

    public void MujPaintHandler(object sender,PaintEventArgs e)   
    {
        Graphics gfx=e.Graphics;  
        gfx.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.DarkViolet),100,100,200,200);  

    }

    public void MujClickHandler(object sender,EventArgs e)      
    { 
        this.Text="aaaaa";

        this.RaisePaintEvent(this, new PaintEventArgs(this.CreateGraphics(), this.RectangleToClient(new Rectangle())));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(MujPaintHandler);
    }
```